# Qual a origem da palavra "frete"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro

Em uma pesquisa rápida eu li que a origem da palavra "frete" vem do idioma Holandês, isso está correto?

O site que eu li fala exatamente isso:

> Veio para o nosso idioma de sua origem no Holandês VRACHT / VRECHT, “transporte de mercadorias e passageiros por água”.

Fonte: [Origem das palavras](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/frete/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece estar **correto**, mas chegou ao português por meio do **francês**.

- Tanto o [Dicionário etimológico de língua portuguesa (DELPo)](http://www.nehilp.org/) do Núcleo de Apoio à Pesquisa em Etimologia e História da Língua Portuguesa da USP, quanto o [dicionário online Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/frete/) afirmam que `frete` se origina do francês *fret*, que [significa](http://www.ultralingua.com/onlinedictionary/dictionary#src_lang=French&dest_lang=Portuguese&query=fret) `carga` em português. E dicionários de francês (por exemplo [este](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fret), [este](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fret/35203?q=fret#35172) e também [este](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fret)) confirmam que *fret* se origina da palavra *vrecht* do **holandês médio** [1] (que corresponde a *vracht* - `frete, carga` - em holandês moderno).
- O [infopedia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/frete) (Porto Editora) e o [TheFreeDictionary](https://pt.thefreedictionary.com/frete), por sua vez, atribuem a origem ao **alto-alemão antigo** -- o que não necessariamente está em contradição com a informação anterior (DELPo e Michaelis), dado que este estágio da língua alemã [cobre o período](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alto-alem%C3%A3o_antigo) de 700 a 1050, enquanto o holandês médio [foi usado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Dutch) de ~1100 a 1500.

  > -- Do antigo alto- al. freht, «recompensa», pelo francês fret, «custo do transporte de uma mercadoria»
  >
  > -- (Do ant. al. freht)

<sub>[1]: Nota: *vrecht*, por sua vez, [se originaria](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vrecht#Middle_Dutch) do holandês antigo (ou [outra língua germânica antiga](http://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/vracht)) *frēht* e, por fim, do hipotético [protogermânico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_protogerm%C3%A2nica) *fra-aih-ti-*, ou **fra-* + **aihtiz*.</sub>

Comment: Na minha terra existe a expressão "Fazer um Frete " que significa estar a ouvir ou fazer algo que lhe desagrada que lhe é indiferente , que preferia não estar a ouvir/fazer

Comment: @ClMend Não conhecia essa expressão, onde ela é usada?

Comment: Na Ilha da Madeira. É muito popular aqui.